# Can't execute binary on macOS catalina

Tags: macos, gatekeeper, catalina

I am trying to run a binary that I have downloaded (it's part of flutter). Whenever I'm trying to run it, I get the error:

[image: "idevice_id" can't be opened because its integrity cannot be verified.]

I have already disabled gatekeeper checks globally with `sudo spctl --master-disable`. What else can I do to get this to run?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/install-spotify-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so error message is slightly different but have a look or comment if you want.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The solution is to remove the `quarantine` attribute from the file(s) in question:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/file
```