# Upgraded to macOS Catalina and now cannot install latest version of SQLDeveloper.app

Tags: error

I am getting the error: “SQLDeveloper.app” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install Spotify" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/install-spotify-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so) and [Can't execute binary on macOS catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367364/cant-execute-binary-on-macos-catalina?noredirect=1&lq=1)