# Getting warning each time i open browser using Epichrome

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome

I am using Epichrome to have multiple Chrome browsers at the same time. I have three browsers that I made with Epichrome, but each time I open one of them, it gives this warning:

[image: Epichrome Warning]

I am using MacOS Catalina (10.15.2) on my MacBook Pro, and the browser I made using Epichrome is called 'Duolingo'.

Does anyone know a fix for this, if not why it is there?

Comment: Would this step be useful ?https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/install-spotify-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so/366546#366546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've occasionally seen this myself, but I've never had it happen every time I launch an Epichrome app. The first thing I'd try is this:

1. Quit all your Epichrome apps.
2. Run the main Google Chrome and go to the About Google Chrome page. If it shows an update pending, tell it to update and relaunch.
3. Once you have confirmed Chrome is up to date, try relaunching your Epichrome apps. You might get the warning the first time you run them, but subsequent runs should not show the warning.

If those steps don't help, please open an issue on the [Github page](https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome/issues/), and I'll try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Works fine, thanks. Are you the creator of Epichrome.

Comment: Yeah, I'm the creator. Glad that worked for you! By the way, Catalina has screwed up a bunch of other things with Epichrome. I'm working on a new version to fix compatibility.

Comment: Cool, thanks. It's the best app ever.

Comment: Thank you--I'm glad it's useful to you!