# How to make app trusted on Big Sur?

Tags: security, big-sur

I want to run SageMath on my mac. It uses python, so whenever I start big-sur asks me to confirm that I want to trust the developer. I know there is the

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

command to disable the protection completely. However, I want to keep that protection enabled. Is there a way to mark the app or developer as trusted?

I have tried this command

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/Sagemath/sage
```

but that doesn`t seem to help, since I have to do it for every single function in SageMath.

Comment: Try the steps here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/install-spotify-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so/366546#366546  I'm surprised that it's required every time, though.