# Adding color pickers to macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, color, ventura, verify

I am migrating from an older iMac to a new Mac Mini. One thing I would like to include are the third party colour pickers to `~/Library/ColorPickers`.

I have copied the colour picker packages, but I can’t use them, because they come from unknown developers. The usual trick of right-click open doesn’t work here.

How can I enable these color pickers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the files don't have quarantine attributes? See my answer here:

["Install Spotify" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/install-spotify-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so/366546#366546)

In this case you can try:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine *.colorPicker
```